# How to join two array entries in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, join

I have one array, and I want to join the 5th and the 6th entry of it!

Like: @array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) should be @array(1,2,3,4,56,7,8,9)

How could i achieve that? I've just found in the internet how to merge two arrays, but not two entries...

Thanks in advance.
Best regards, John.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html), along with an [array slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

splice @array, 4, 2, join('', @array[4,5]);

print "@array";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
my @b = (@a[0..3], join('',@a[4..5]), @a[6..8]);

print "@b\n";   # <---- prints: 1 2 3 4 56 7 8 9
```